# Can you style the first and last elements in a panel via pure XAML and without explicitly applying a style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, position, panel

Ok, I know in DataBinding you can easily target the first or last bound item, but I'm wondering if there's any way for you to style the first and last item in a subclass of Panel implicitly (e.g. without adding anything identifying which is the first or last.  I just want to use the ordinal position.)

For instance, I have this...

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1">
    <RadioButton Content="First" />
    <RadioButton Content="Middle" />
    <RadioButton Content="Another Middle" />
    <RadioButton Content="Last" />
</UniformGrid>
```

...and I want to target a style at the first item and a second one at the last item.

That said, I know I can...

1. Add an explicit style to the first and last item, or
2. Add an explicit attached property to the first and last item and use that in a style trigger. (This is the way I'm leaning.)

...but again, I'm hoping to avoid both of those and go pure-XAML with implicit styling.

So, can it be done?

---

**UPDATE**:

For now, I ended up just going the generic attached-property approach.  I created an AP called `UIHelper.Position` that has the values First, Last, and Default.  We then reference it in the triggers inside the template and style accordingly.

It still requires us to 'tag' the controls with the attached property, but it gets us over the hump, and avoids having to create multiple styles with multiple templates. (Our template internally used CornerRadius which isn't a property on the templated control so we couldn't simply style it away.  It had to be done in triggers.)

Still, if anyone knows how to do this without resorting to an attached property, feel free to answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that comes immediately to mind is use a Template Selector.  You might try to find away to evaluate the objects location in the collection in which it resides and base the selection of Template on that.

```
If myCollection.IndexOf(myObj) = 0 Or myCollection.IndexOf(myObj) = myCollection.Count Then
    Return TryCast(container.FindResource("FirstLastTemplate"), DataTemplate)
Else
    Return TryCast(container.FindResource("MiddleTemplate"), DataTemplate)
End If
```

Havent tested it, but seems like it would work. If you are using MVVM, you could get access to your ViewModel via the container (I think).

Comment: Yeah, thought about that, but didn't want to have to resort to multiple templates.  Actually, we can't use them anyway without manually re-creating the template itself because the template uses properties like CornerRadius which aren't present on the control we're applying it to (e.g. we can't use TemplateBinding or any binding for that matter.)  I ended up just creating a generic attached property to handle it.  I'll add it in the question above.